# How to detect the view in GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener

Tags: android, android-layout

I have gesturedetector class like the following

```
    class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
@Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "onSingleTapConfirmed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
}
```

Now I am attaching this detector with two of my views in onCreate method,

```
mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity(), new MyGestureListener());

        profileImage.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                    return mDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }
        });

        topButtonLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return mDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
            }
        });
```

The listeners are working for both views. But I would like to detect/identify the view which has created the event. Please let me know if there is any way to do that.

Answer (score -1):

You can check the id of the view on Touch()

```
 public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
           switch(view.getId()){
              case R.id.view1:
                    // Do action for view1
                   break;
              case R.id.view2:
                    // Do action for view2
                   break;  
           }
        }
```

Comment: he probably wants to know it when `onSingleTapConfirmed` is triggered

Comment: Thanks john, but is it possible to identify the view within the gesture detector class?